# BV estimate for conservation law $u_t +( v(x)f(u))_x=0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

Let $u_0 \in BV(\mathbb R)$ and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be Lipschitz. Consider the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{align*}
u_t +( v(x)f(u))_x&=0\\
u(0,\cdot) &= u_0
\end{align*}
$$

What is the minimal assumption that we need to put on $v$ to prove $u(t,\cdot) \in BV(\mathbb R)$?

From a formal computation, I think we need $v' \in BV(\mathbb R)$, but my intuition would have been the weaker condition $v' \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.